# Fitting text into an SVG path

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have an SVG path that draws the outline of a jersey, and I want to center players' last names within that jersey. Also, since I'll be putting names of varying length into the jersey, I wanted to make the size of the text dynamically scale to fit the jersey.

I was able to center the text with some math involving getBoundingClientRect(), but I'm struggling with the dynamic sizing of the text. It looks fine at first, but then when I resize the screen, the text size does not remain proportional to the size of jersey.

I've included a code snippet below to demonstrate. Please help me understand why this sizing issue is occurring, and what I can do to achieve the proper text resizing.

EDIT: I now have enough reputation points to add images (woo!), so here are some pictures to demonstrate the resizing problem I'm referring to. The text does not scale proportionally with the jersey size when I zoom in/out. BUT, if I refresh the page after I zoom in/out, i.e. so that I start out with the zoomed-in/out version, the text size readjusts to the current jersey size and fits the jersey as desired.

[image: original size]
[image: zoomed out]
[image: zoomed in]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Jersey</title>
</head>

<body>
  <svg id="jersey">
    <switch>
      <g>
        <g id="jerseyShape">
          <path id="outline" fill="green" transform="translate(-40,0)" opacity="0.35" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.5" d="M116.462,113.911V39.01
                           c0,0-18.493-5.977-15.317-30.633c0,0-8.033-2.616-8.78-3.363S91.617,9.311,79.29,9.124h-1.305
                           C65.656,9.311,65.656,4.268,64.909,5.015s-8.778,3.363-8.778,3.363C59.305,33.034,40.813,39.01,40.813,39.01v74.901
                           C40.813,113.911,74.434,126.427,116.462,113.911z" />
        </g>
        <g id="jerseyContent">
          <svg>
            <text id="name" font-family="Verdana" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central">
              Jordan
            </text>
            <!-- Dynamically re-size name to fit jersey -->
            <script type="application/ecmascript">
              //Get path's bounding rectangle
              var pathNode = document.getElementById("outline");
              var pRect = pathNode.getBoundingClientRect();

              //Get text's bounding rectangle
              var textNode = document.getElementById("name");
              var tRect = textNode.getBBox();

              //Calculate the necessary scale to make the text fit within the jersey width while
              //not exceeding a height of 30
              var widthRatio = (pRect.width * 0.85) / tRect.width;
              var heightRatio = (pRect.height*0.3) / tRect.height;
              var textScale = Math.min(widthRatio, heightRatio);

              //Translate text to center of jersey and scale to fit
              textNode.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + (1 + pRect.width / 2) + " " + (pRect.top + pRect.height / 2) + ")scale(" + textScale + ")");
            </script>
          </svg>
        </g>
      </g>
    </switch>
  </svg>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm not able to get the jersey to resize with the window at all using your code.

Comment: what browser? latest Chrome/Windows seems to be fine

Comment: Thanks for asking that Michael, I'm embarrassed to say I hadn't tested out different browsers (still sort of new to web dev!). You're right, I don't see the issue when on Chrome, and I also don't see it on Firefox (though Firefox appears to have a completely different alignment issue). I was only looking at Safari. I'm mildly surprised/concerned/discouraged to see each browser have such different behavior -- this is bound to make things difficult going forward!

Answer (score 1):

You should also use `getBBox()` fo get the size of the path as well.  That way, the dimensions will be in the same coordinate space even after scaling.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I'll definitely dig around to understand the difference between getBoundingClientRect() and getBBox(). What about for webpage zooms though (i.e. ctrl+ or ctrl-)? Neither of these functions seem to give me the right scaling behavior when I perform a webpage zoom, i.e. the text doesn't grow proportionally to the jersey. It looks like the issue is that the functions don't re-compute upon webpage zooms, because when I zoom and then refresh the page, everything appears to be recalculated and the scaling is perfect. Can these function re-compute bounding boxes after webpage zooms?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you are calculating the scale on the group which contains the textnode.

I have solved you problem by giving the scale on the whole g element with id= "full"

So now you can change the scale value on **id="full"** and get desired result without the label going out.
I have updated the code such that it takes into account the scale value on zoom in zoom out (ctrl +/ ctrl -)

```js
$(window).on("resize", function(){ 
  var scale = "scale("+window.devicePixelRatio+")"
  $("#full").attr("transform", scale)
  console.log($("#full").attr("transform"));
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Jersey</title>
    </head>
    
    <body style="width:100%; height:100%">
      <svg style="    height: 602px;    width: 100%;">
          <g id="full" transform="scale(1)">
            <g id="jerseyShape" transform="translate(-40,0)">
              <path id="outline" fill="green" opacity="0.35" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1.5" d="M116.462,113.911V39.01
                               c0,0-18.493-5.977-15.317-30.633c0,0-8.033-2.616-8.78-3.363S91.617,9.311,79.29,9.124h-1.305
                               C65.656,9.311,65.656,4.268,64.909,5.015s-8.778,3.363-8.778,3.363C59.305,33.034,40.813,39.01,40.813,39.01v74.901
                               C40.813,113.911,74.434,126.427,116.462,113.911z" />
                <text id="name" transform="translate(80,80)" font-family="Verdana" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="central">
                  Jordan
                </text>                           
            </g>
          </g>
      </svg>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Cyril. When I run the snippet though, it seems to have the same text resizing issue as before -- when I zoom in, the text spills over the sides of the jersey. Am I missing something? Also, where did the scale value of 2.7 come from?

Comment: Oh now I see what you meant here. 2.7 was of course arbitrary, and by changing that value, both the jersey and the text will scale together. Thanks for pointing this out as it is also helpful to me, but doesn't fix my original problem. I meant if I zoom in (like, actually zoom the webpage via ctrl+ or ctrl-, not just scale the group), the text doesn't grow/shrink proportionally with the jersey. (also, I deliberately included scaling logic for the textnode, b/c the names can be arbitrarily long, and I need the text height to scale down so that the full name fits within the jersey.)

Comment: Yes correct the 2.7 is just an arbitrary number which you can change.
Ok can you listen to the zoom in/zoom out event and calculate the scale accordingly. That should solve your problem.

Comment: Ok i have updated my code.
To address the ctrl + and ctrl -.
I am sure it will address all your concerns now :)

Comment: Thanks for the update! A comment from Michael Mullany to my original question made me realize that my issue is actually Safari-specific, so your code works like a charm in Chrome and Firefox, but if you happen to have Safari installed you may observe that the text scaling behaves weirdly still. I'm realizing that cross-browser support will be a huge challenge, and it may just be best for me to focus on Chrome & Firefox going forward...

Comment: Oh ok, the problem in safari is that window.devicePixelRatio is always 1 and so the scaling does not work...:(
Need a special handling to get the pixel ratio on safari and that should nail it.